# Python 3 Stringio + PIL + Requests get image from url

Tags: python, python-requests, python-imaging-library, stringio

I am heving troubles migrating to python 3. This is my code:

```
from io import StringIO
from PIL import Image
import requests
r = requests.get(imagen_url)
imagen = Image.open(StringIO(r.content))
```

It used to work on python 2. This is the error I get:

> initial_value must be str or None, not bytes

Comment: Try with `r.text` and tell us. What do normally return the request ?

Comment: I get this: StringIO cannot be used to open an image. Binary data must be used instead.